# get " java.lang.StackOverflowError: null " when using Helpers.fakeApplcation in play 2.3.2 unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework-2.0

I want to try Java unit testing using fakeApplication in play 2.3 framework. My code is like this:

```
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.running;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.test.WithApplication;

public class ApplicationTest extends WithApplication {

    @Test
    public void simpleCheck() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int a = 1 + 1;
                assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
[error] Test ApplicationTest.simpleCheck failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null, took 3.862 sec
[error]     at java.lang.String.regionMatches(String.java:1326)
[error]     at java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(String.java:1090)
[error]     at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory.getLogger(JDK14LoggerFactory.java:55)
[error]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
[error]     at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:204)
[error]     at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:291)
[error]     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:610)
[error]     at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:579)
.
.
.
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         ApplicationTest
[error] (test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
```

The test passes when I don't use fakeApplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFunctionalTest), `WithApplication` *"automatically ensure that a fake application is started and stopped for you"*

So you do not need to start a new one in your test if you extend `WithApplication`.
Try this :

```
public class ApplicationTest extends WithApplication {
    @Test
    public void simpleCheck() {
        int a = 1 + 1;
        assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
    }
}
```

or this

```
public class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void simpleCheck() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int a = 1 + 1;
                assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was existing of different versions of slf4j jar files in my unmanaged dependencies. I deleted those jars and problem solved :)